# Why does using LTO increase the size of my Rust binary?

Tags: rust, compiler-optimization, lto

### Introduction

I finished a small Rust project (about 300 lines of code) with the following dependencies:

- [rumqtt](https://crates.io/crates/rumqtt)
- [signal](https://crates.io/crates/signal)
- [log](https://crates.io/crates/log)
- [env_logger](https://crates.io/crates/env_logger)

### Problem

When using `cargo build --release` without further configuration, a 2.942.744 bytes (= 2,8 MiB) binary is generated. I tried to optimize this by enabling Link Time Optimization (LTO) in my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[profile.release]
lto = true
```

To my surprise, the binary grows, with a new size of 3.848.288 bytes (= 3,7 MiB).

How can this be explained? Is there any mistake I made configuring Cargo?

Comment: you may be interested in [this IRLO thread](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/rust-staticlibs-and-optimizing-for-size/5746)

Comment: Why do yo expect the binary size to go down?

Comment: @MatthieuM. In fact, because of [this](https://lifthrasiir.github.io/rustlog/why-is-a-rust-executable-large.html). I didn't know that LTO doesn't just optimize binary size but performance, too.

Comment: @PEAR: I see! It's a bit more complicated than that, actually.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### What is LTO?

LTO means Link-Time Optimization. It is generally set up to use the regular optimization passes used to produce object files... at link time instead, or in addition.

### Why does it matter?

A compiler does not inherently optimize for speed over size or size over speed; and therefore neither does LTO.

Instead, when invoking the compiler, the user selects a profile. For `rustc`:

- `O0`, `O1`, `O2` and `O3` are optimizing for speed.
- `Os` and `Oz` are optimizing for size.

LTO can be combined on top of any optimization level, and will follow the selected profile.

### So why did the size increase?

By default, the `[release]` profile instructs `cargo` to invoke `rustc` with `O2` or `O3`, which *attempts* to optimize for speed over size.

In particular, `O3` can rely quite heavily on inlining. Inlining is all about giving more context to the optimizer, and therefore more optimization opportunities... LTO offers more chances to apply inlining (more known functions), and here it appears that more inlining happened.

### So why did [this blog post](https://lifthrasiir.github.io/rustlog/why-is-a-rust-executable-large.html) claim it reduced size?

It also reduces size. Possibly.

By giving more context, the optimizer/linker can realize that some portion of the code or dependencies are not used at all, and therefore can be elided.

If using `Os` or `Oz`, the size is near certain to go down.

If using `O2` or `O3`, unused code is removed while inlining adds more code, so it's quite unpredictable whether the end result is bigger or smaller.

### So, LTO?

LTO gives the optimizer a better opportunity at optimizing, so it's a good default for Releases.

Just remember that `cargo` leans toward speed over size by default, and if this does not suit you, you may want to select another optimization direction.

Answer (score 6):

Probably because of inlining, which can increase code size to increase speed.

Comment: Is LTO actually able to inline functions? Because that needs a recompilation of that particular function. Can you please provide some documentation?

Comment: What do you mean by recompilation? It is possible to cache generated object files of external crates and optimize every inlined function one by on every calling site.

Comment: @EkremDinçel: I think "recompilation" means "code generation" here. But yes, inlining is one of the very purposes of LTO. https://eklitzke.org/how-gcc-lto-works